# In Gtk#, why is my MenuToolItem not displaying its Menu?

Tags: c#, gtk, gtk#

I want to add a `MenuToolItem` to my Toolbar. It contains two `RadioMenuItem`s. However, when I click the drop-down arrow, I see this:

[image]

This is my current code:

```
MenuToolButton reviewModeToolButton =
    new MenuToolButton (Stock.Preferences);
toolbar.Add (reviewModeToolButton);

Menu reviewModeMenu = new Menu ();
reviewModeToolButton.Menu = reviewModeMenu;

RadioMenuItem normalMenuItem = new RadioMenuItem ("Normal Mode");
RadioMenuItem cramMenuItem =
    new RadioMenuItem (normalMenuItem, "Cram Mode");
reviewModeMenu.Add (normalMenuItem);
reviewModeMenu.Add (cramMenuItem);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add at the end:

```
reviewModeMenu.ShowAll ();
```

At default newly created widgets are not in visible state.

Comment: I don't understand the criteria of the ShowAll() method of the Window then... Is is stopping after an X level of recursion?